# How to set Date Range in Symfony DateType with single_text widget

Tags: php, forms, symfony, date, range

I want to create a date input with the `widget => single_text` type, but I only want the user to be able to select/type years between 2000 and 2099. With `widget => choice` this works fine, but with `single_text` I can write the number I want despite clearly having the range attribute set. Is there a quick way to accomplish this, or do I have to create some other validation? If so, how?

[image: this is how it looks like with single_text]

My code:

```
... ['respiteDate', DateType::class, [
               'required' => false,
               'widget' => 'single_text',
               'years'  =>  range(2000,2099)
               ],
           ], ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a screenshot of Chrome-specific datepicker (if not mistaken). Different browsers do it in a different way and when it comes to `<input type="date"/>` ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)) their is no way to specific which years in particular are to be permitted (contrary to `choice` variant).

According to [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-min-and-max-attributes), there is a way to specify `min` and `max` date, which you may find suitable enough - you just need to specify `min="2000-01-01` and `max="2099-12-31"`.

Interestingly enough, `DateType` does not seem to support `min` and `max` attributes, so be sure to include server-side validation...

Hope this helps...